# selecting minimum of value with all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table Result :

```
        ID      CAt     date            BS  BD
        19048   4       12/10/2013    132   68
        19048   4       12/10/2013 2:43 138 78
        19048   4       12/10/2013 2:44 128 74
        19048   4       12/10/2013 2:45 140 80
        19048   4       6/30/2014 22:07 146 88
        19048   4       6/30/2014 22:07 148 88
        19048   4       6/30/2014 22:08 138 86
        19048   4       6/30/2014 22:08 132 80
```

I want min of bs and BD for each ID and date.

Expected output

```
        ID      CAt date                NAME    Value
        19048   4   12/10/2013          BS      128
        19048   4   12/10/2013          BD      68
        19048   4   6/30/2014           BS      132
        19048   4   6/30/2014           BD      80
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: How many expected output you want ?

Comment: I want    Output 2 bro @Prdp

Comment: @rohit that's not how it works. You need to show your effort first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `Group By` and `Min` aggregate.

Try this way

```
select ID,CAt, min([date]),Min(BS),Min(BD)
From yourtable 
Group by ID,CAt,cast([date] as Date)
```

`cast([date] as Date)` in `group by` is used to find the min `BS` and `BD` for each `date`

For second output you need to unpivot the data

```
SELECT ID,CAt,[date] = Min([date]),name,value = Min(value)
FROM   yourtable
       CROSS apply (VALUES ('bs',bs),
                           ('bd',bd)) cs (name, value)
GROUP  BY ID,CAt,Cast([date] AS DATE),name
```

Comment: thnks can you Give me Output 2 . @prdp

Comment: @rohitpatil - Check the second query

Answer (score 1):

First Group by ID, CAt, date and get min and max value from grouped rows:

```
    select ID, CAt, date, 
    (case when BS>=0 then 'BS' else 'BD' end ) as NAME ,
    (case when BS>=0 then BS else BD end ) as Value from
   ( select ID, CAt, date , min(BS) as BS, -1 as BD 
    from table_name
    group by ID, CAt, date
    union all 
    select ID, CAt, date , -1 as BS, min(BD) as BD 
    from table_name
    group by ID, CAt, date
    ) as A
```

You also group by different group of column as per requirement.

Comment: Good Onr thnks. ITs perfect. But add min() function.

Answer (score 0):

MIN() selects minimum value according to group by condition. Date() selects only date portion of DATETIME column

```
SELECT ID , CAT, n.DATE, min(BS) AS BS, min(BD) AS BD FROM test.new_table AS n group by ID, Date(n.DATE);
```